# How do I leave space blank when field is not rendered on visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, rerender

I am facing layout related problem when field is not rendered. set of fields are moving from one place to another while fields reRender. Please look at the screenshots attached as well as Code. Can some one help me resolve this issue please?

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:actionRegion renderRegionOnly="true">
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="section2" columns="2">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Industry}">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="section2" />
                </apex:inputField>

                <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Rating}" rendered="{!Account.Industry='Technology'}">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="section2" />
                </apex:inputField>

                <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Phone}" rendered="{!Account.Rating='Hot'}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Fax}" />
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
                <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Site}" />
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
                <apex:inputField value="{!Account.DunsNumber}" />
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
                <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Jigsaw}" />
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:actionRegion>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do? What fields do you want where?

Comment: @EricSSH I want all that to be lined up in one queue except rating field on right of industry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>` and put its 'rendered' condition to be the opposite of what you want

Example:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!Account.Industry !='Technology'}" />
```

Comment: Wow. Fabulous solution. I couldn't think that way. Thank you for your answer.